# postgresql on macports not working. idk password

Tags: django, postgresql

I installed postgesql from mac ports with the intention of running it on a django framework. Here are the commands that I used:

```
sudo port install postgresql84-server
sudo port install py26-psycopg2
```

After the installation I would like to now try to test a database by 1. forming it and 2. accessing it. The first problem I have is when I try to get into psql I have to enter a password that I dont know. Do you know where I can find this password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL role's password (probably unset/empty at beginning) is completely different thing than Mac OS user's password. It should be possible to authenticate with [`ident`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) method as `postgres` Mac user using `psql` command (`psql -U postgres postgres` is implicit). After that you can set postgres role's password.

```
$ whoami
postgres
$ psql
psql (8.4.8)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW password_encryption; -- making sure that password will be MD5 encrypted
 password_encryption 
---------------------
 on
(1 row)
postgres=# ALTER ROLE postgres PASSWORD 'yourSecretPassword';
postgres=# SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname LIKE 'postgres';
             rolpassword             
-------------------------------------
 md5738d021d4bc194576641fa9936656836
(1 row)
```

If this is not possible, then add following line as **first** rule in your `pg_hba.conf` (don't forget to reload/restart your server/cluster):

```
local   all         postgres                          ident
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, postgres is configured with `ident sameuser` authentication;  That means you must actually be the `postgres` user to connect to the database or create new roles.  become that user with `su - postgres`.

Comment: I tried this and it asks me for another password. I'm just confused as to what password its asking me for

Comment: `su` requires the system's root password, which you will have set when you initially installed or configured your system.   Once you have become the postgres user, you can log into the database without a password.  Alternatively, you can edit `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` to use a different authentication scheme